# Get Office creation by year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to count Offices creations grouped by year.

The problem is, the `Offices` table doesn't have a `CreationDate` column.

So, the only way of getting a date for office creation, is looking in another column, where offices license purchases are stored, because there is a date.

Let's say I have these tables:

`Offices` table:

```
Id  Name
--------------------
1   Office One
133 Maria's Office
230 John's Office
```

`LicensePurchases` table:

```
Id  OfficeId    PurchaseDate
---------------------------------------------
1      1        2016-11-17 00:00:00.000
2    133        2016-12-23 00:00:00.000
3      1        2017-01-27 00:00:00.000
4    230        2023-04-11 00:00:00.000
5    133        2023-04-12 00:00:00.000
6      1        2023-04-13 00:00:00.000
7      1        2023-04-17 00:00:00.000
```

I am trying to adapt this query, but not success so far:

```
DECLARE @year int = 2020;

SELECT DISTINCT
    cc.OfficeId AS Office_Id,
    c.Name AS NAME,
    (SELECT TOP 1 cc.PurchaseDate
     FROM LicensesPurchase cc 
     WHERE cc.OfficeId = c.OfficeId 
       AND YEAR(cc.PurchaseDate) = @year 
     ORDER BY cc.PurchaseDate) AS First_Purchase_Date,
    (SELECT TOP 1 cc.PurchaseDate
     FROM LicensesPurchase cc
     WHERE cc.OfficeId = c.OfficeId 
     ORDER BY cc.PurchaseDate DESC) AS Last_Purchase_Date
FROM 
    LicensesPurchase cc 
LEFT JOIN 
    Office c ON c.OfficeId = cc.OfficeId
WHERE 
    c.Status = 18 -- ACTIVE
    AND YEAR(cc.PurchaseDate) >= @year
```

I tried Join, but other problem is, since there will be more than one purchase, I will need to consider the oldest one, to match the Office creation.

So, how would I get this?

Comment: Have you considered getting the year of the `MIN` value?

Comment: Also it would be helpful to provide the attempt(s) made so we can steer you in the right direction.

Comment: join the LicensePurchases  grouped by offceid and MIN(PurchaseDate) to the Offices

Comment: Please show your desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you need. The subquery just gets the year of the oldest purchase date by office, then just join back to the offices table.

```
SELECT 
    o.Id, o.Name,
    lp.OldestPurchaseDate
    FROM Offices o 
        JOIN (SELECT OfficeId, YEAR(MIN(PurchaseDate)) AS OldestPurchaseDate
                FROM LicensePurchases 
                GROUP BY OfficeID
                ) lp
            ON o.Id = lp.OfficeId
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT o.id, o.name, d.firstdate
FROM Offices AS o
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT MIN(purchasedate) AS firstdate
    FROM LicensePurchases AS l
    WHERE l.officeid = o.id
    AND purchasedate>'20200101' ) AS d
WHERE o.status=18;
```